# Best suitable type of Intraclass correlation method?

Tags: r, mixed-model, normalization, reliability, intraclass-correlation

I would like to understand if the below data is suitable to run single_raters_absolute IntraClass Correlation (ICC) or Single_random_raters or Single_fixed_raters. I have executed the below program in R generated different types of above mentioned output results. I am unable to decide which is the best suitable result for the data below. Please can someone expain?

```
GP_Id Pat_Id    Total_prescribed_prescriptions
1   a   1
1   b   2
1   c   4
1   d   1
1   e   2
2   f   7
2   g   2
2   h   1
2   i   7
3   j   8
3   k   9
3   l   4
3   m   6
3   n   4
```

Program1

```
library(psych)
ICC(R_COM)
```

output1

```
Intraclass correlation coefficients 
                         type      ICC    F  df1  df2    p lower bound upper bound
Single_raters_absolute   ICC1 -0.60834 0.24 4762 4763 1.00     -0.6231     -0.5931
Single_random_raters     ICC2  0.00065 1.01 4762 4762 0.43     -0.0051      0.0067
Single_fixed_raters      ICC3  0.00269 1.01 4762 4762 0.43     -0.0211      0.0265
Average_raters_absolute ICC1k -3.10647 0.24 4762 4763 1.00     -3.3070     -2.9153
Average_random_raters   ICC2k  0.00130 1.01 4762 4762 0.43     -0.0103      0.0132
Average_fixed_raters    ICC3k  0.00537 1.01 4762 4762 0.43     -0.0432      0.0517
```

Program2

```
library(psych)
ICC(R_COM)
```

Output 2

```
Single Score Intraclass Correlation

   Model: twoway 
   Type : agreement 

   Subjects = 4763 
     Raters = 2 
   ICC(A,1) = 0.000654

 F-Test, H0: r0 = 0 ; H1: r0 > 0 
F(4762,4447) = 1.01 , p = 0.428 

 95%-Confidence Interval for ICC Population Values:
  -0.006 < ICC < 0.008
```

Comment: ICC stands for intraclass correlation, not intercluster correlation. I don't think the tags are relevant here, and [tag:intraclass-correlation] would be a better option, IMO. Is this the full dataset?

Comment: Hi,Thank for correcting me. I have updated in my question and the title. This is not the full dataset but the data look very similar.